# I18N and L10N in WPF through XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, localization, internationalization

If anybody know how to do the **Internationalization and localization in WPF through only XAML**. I have already done through WPF .cs file by using Resource Manager class.
  ***I would greatly appericiate, if anybody can guide me and given me the code samples.***

Thanks in advance,

Cheers...
Karthikeyan Manickam.

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at http://www.microsoft.com/uk/remix08/agenda.aspx. In particular select "Day two" -> *Internationalizing WPF And Silverlight Applications*.

Comment: I used the PPT of that presentation to save time: http://download.microsoft.com/documents/uk/remix08/day2/01_GuySmithFerrier_WPF.pptx

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer available. Use the .ppt link provided by @OneWorld

Answer (score 1):

Use localization tool. We use Sisulizer
http://www.sisulizer.com

It can easily make localized XAML files and satellite assembly files. No need to modify your existig XAML files.